# Combine all same vendorID's into a single object and corresponding productID's into the products array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of objects as shown below

```
let obj = [
            {vendorID: 101, productID: "A"},
            {vendorID: 102, productID: "B"},
            {vendorID: 101, productID: "C"},
            {vendorID: 102, productID: "D"}     
]
```

I need it to be converted in the below fashion

```
expected_output = 
[
  {
    vendorID: 101,
    products: [
      {
        productID: "A",
        productID: "C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    vendorID:102,
    products: [
      {
        productID:"B",
        productID:"D"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I implement this in Javascript ?

Comment: Consider using `reduce`?

Comment: I'm able to get distinct vendorID's but the productID's are not getting pushed into the products array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
products: [
  {
    productID: "A",
    productID: "C"
  }
]
```

You just can't get as a result that kind of structure because JS objects have unique keys.

But if it's OK for you to get this kind of structure

```js
expected_output = [
  {
    vendorID: 101,
    productIDs: ["A", "C"]
  },
  {
    vendorID:102,
    productIDs: ["B", "D"]
  }
];
```

just use the next

```js
obj.reduce((acc, { vendorID, productID }) => {
  const vendor = acc.find(e => e.vendorID === vendorID);

  if(!vendor) {
    return [
      ...acc,
      {
        vendorID,
        productIDs: [productID],
      },
    ];
  }

  vendor.productIDs.push(productID);
  return acc;
}, []);
```